# Minimum number of exchanges

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Suppose we want to arrange n numbers stored in an array such that all negative value occur before the positive ones. What will be the minimum number of exchanges in the worst case ?

I tried it in the following way :

the worst case would be when we have the positives and negatives arranged in an alternate fashion. So, minimum number of exchanges could be (n/2) + (n-2)/2 + (n-4)/2 + ....

here, I am getting confused regarding calculating this sum. after first series of exchanges we could eliminate the last two and then left with n-2 numbers.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: I don't know about the minimum but I think the quicksort partition step using 0 as a pivot should come close.

Comment: i have edited my question. `lhf` sir, Can you give me a very precise answer ? Thanks for the comment btw.

Comment: Do you have an algorithm in mind?  Is it required that exchanges be of adjacent elements?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algorithm for the minimal number of swaps.

1. Count the number of negatives in the array.  Let this number be $m$.
2. Swap any positives in positions $[1,\ldots,m]$ with negatives in positions $[m+1,\ldots,n]$.

Since each swap ensures two positions in the array are correct, at most $\frac{n}{2}$ swaps are needed to ensure all positions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You define optimum for an algorithm in terms of number of swaps.

A swap can at most move 2 items into the correct place.

If a list is not in order, then there exist at least two items out of place.  Therefore there exists an algorithm which puts 2 items into the correct place with each swap.

There exists a worst for the optimal algorithm case which has every item out of place:  $\frac N 2$ positive values followed by $\frac N 2$ negative values.

There for the worst case number of swaps is $\frac N 2$.

Comment: "Each swap puts both values into a correct place" -- not necessarily.  Imagine $1$ positive followed by $n-1$ negatives.  Depending on which swaps you make, this could take anywhere from $1$ to $n-1$ swaps.  You need to specify the swapping algorithm more precisely for this to work.

Comment: Comment appreciated, I rewrote the post.  However, you don't actually need to specify the algorithm.  You only need to establish that there exists an algorithm with the necessary properties, which to go into detail with would be a bit obtuse in my opinion.  No matter how specific you are, if you aren't using symbolic logic, then you could always be more specific, so I believe saying enough to be understood is sufficient.

Comment: However, this is still not quite right.  By your argument, a list should be able to be sorted in arbitrary order in $n/2$ swaps.  But some permutations of list order (e.g. rotation) require up to $n$ swaps.

Comment: I think we are disagreeing on the interpretation of the question.  The poster said a list is in order when negatives are before positives.  In such case, {-1, -2, 100, 4} is in order.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but your argument is wrong.  You argue that "If a list is not in order, then there exists at least two items out of place.  Therefore there exists an algorithm which puts 2 items into the correct place with each swap."  This reasoning is false in general, as the rotation example shows.

Comment: Could you write an example of a rotated list?

Comment: Suppose we have a list $[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ and we want to produce the list $[x_2, \ldots, x_n, x_1]$.  Initially, every element is out of place, but no swap puts $2$ items in the correct place.

Comment: No such example such as you have listed exists for this problem.  If you have [-5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, -7], then swapping 1 and -7 puts the 2 in place: [-5, -3, -1, -7, 3, 5, 7, 1], and the list is now sorted as the poster defined.

Comment: True, but your logic is wrong.  You haven't justified the assertion that you can always swap two elements such that both end up in the correct places.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my vision.

Suppose you have $n_1$ of negative numbers. Then, after the procedure you must have all of the $[1..n_1]$ numbers negative. So, the number of operations is $n_1 - h_1$, where $h_1$ is the number of negative elements already in $[1..n_1]$. The same goes about positive numbers - we can place them at the end of the array with $n_2 - h_2$ operation (I believe you can see what the notation mean).

The overall number of operations is $min(n_1 - h_1, n_2 - h_2)$

It's not difficult to see, that the value of the minimum is $n/2$.